# Jquery UI Combo box is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI combo box and its not working here is my code its giving the following error, which I see in firefox console.

**Error**

TypeError: input.data("autocomplete") is undefined
[Break On This Error]

input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

**Javascript**

```
 (function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.combobox", {
        _create: function () {
            var input,
                self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children(":selected"),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
                wrapper = this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                    .addClass("ui-combobox")
                    .insertAfter(select);

            input = $("<input>")
                .appendTo(wrapper)
                .val(value)
                .addClass("ui-state-default ui-combobox-input")
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                        response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                            var text = $(this).text();
                            if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }));
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger("selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },
                    change: function (event, ui) {
                        if (!ui.item) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                valid = false;
                            select.children("option").each(function () {
                                if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if (!valid) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $(this).val("");
                                select.val("");
                                input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

            input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };

            $("<a>")
                .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                .appendTo(wrapper)
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
                .click(function () {
                    // close if already visible
                    if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                        input.autocomplete("close");
                        return;
                    }

                    // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                    $(this).blur();

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                    input.focus();
                });
        },

        destroy: function () {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(function () {

    $("#combobox").combobox();



});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="ui-widget">

<select id="combobox">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <option value="@item.Name">@item.Name</option>
        }
</select>
```

i don't know why but its not working  . Please help me

Comment: You must have a problem in your loop. Could you provide the generated source code of <options> part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

autocomplete was conflicting with elr_notify.js , so its resolved

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have called the same jquery js files in layout pages and in the current page, go to shared folder and find the view and check the corresponding layout page, this caused to me due to conflict